# changing text while streaming live video

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a scrip for live streaming with picamera and raspberryPi, I want to change brightness and show its value on the screen using "camera.annotate_text" but what I get is a static number, how can I show the current brightness value on the screen?

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard
import sys

camera = PiCamera()
camera.brightness =50
def increase():
    was_pressed = False
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
            if not was_pressed:
                if camera.brightness<100 :
                    camera.brightness += 5
                    was_pressed= True
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
            if not was_pressed:
                if camera.brightness>0 :
                    camera.brightness -= 5
                    was_pressed= True
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('m'):
            if not was_pressed:
                sys.exit()                                      
        else:
            was_pressed = False
try:
    while True:
        camera.start_preview()
        camera.annotate_text='B:%i'%camera.brightness
        increase()
    sleep(1000)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: `increase()` has an infinite loop. It will never return (except `sys.exit`).

Comment: why do you have two `while True` loops ? You should have only one and do all inside this loop

Comment: how can I fix it? could u help me?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it at this moment but it should be only one loop or at least you should use `camera.annotate_text` in first loop

```
import keyboard
import sys

camera = PiCamera()
camera.brightness = 50

def increase():
    was_pressed = False
    while True:

        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
            if not was_pressed:
                if camera.brightness<100 :
                    camera.brightness += 5
                    was_pressed= True
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
            if not was_pressed:
                if camera.brightness>0 :
                    camera.brightness -= 5
                    was_pressed= True
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('m'):
            if not was_pressed:
                sys.exit()                                      
        else:
            was_pressed = False

        camera.annotate_text='B:%i'%camera.brightness

try:
    camera.start_preview()
    increase()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    camera.stop_preview()
```